# symfony forms entityField set selected value

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want set the "selected" value when editing the Form.

```
->add('mitarbeiter', EntityType::class, array(
                'placeholder' => 'Wähle einen Mitarbeiter',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Sidatuser',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->orderBy('s.Vorname', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
```

in the Controller ($data is the Entity Object)

```
$form = $this->createForm(KursteilnehmerType::class, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object (entity) to set the defaults:

```
//get $mitarbeiter from the database (for example)
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Mitarbeiter');
$mitarbeiter = $repo->findOneByUsername('StephanVierkant');

// add your entity here
// or whatever your entity is called, mein deutsch ist nicht so gut ;-)
$data = new Kursteilnehmer();
$data->setMitarbeiter($mitarbeiter);

$form = $this->createForm(KursteilnehmerType::class, $data);
```

Please not that you don't have to `persist` and `flush` your entity here, since you'll do that when you save to form.

Read more about this in the [Form documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). Take a look at the Task-example.